# Consulta inteligente com MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta mais "inteligente" no meu DB,
a minha dúvida é como?

Tenho uma *query*:

```
SELECT * from publicacao where titulo like '%$busca%';
```

e no meu DB tem vários títulos de publicação, por exemplo:

```
Farmácia
Pharmácia
Pharmacia
Farmacia
```

Ao buscar por farmácia, deveriam ser retornadas as 4 linhas.

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Se você der um like em `cia` ele vai trazer, mas vai trazer mais coisas tb... Tem pouca informação para dar uma resposta melhor (pelo menos pra mim :) )

Comment: entao a palavra buscada poderia ser uma das 4 e voltaria sempre as 4 linhas ou todas q tivese farmacia numa dessas variações

Comment: Pesquise sobre FTS (full text search). O acento não tem problema nenhum, o MySQL faz nativamente se você usar uma collation internacional (seja em UTF-8, ou Latin/ISO, funciona muito bem, só precisa escolher uma compatível com o encoding). No caso do PH já muda um pouco.

Comment: Entendi, já trabalhei em um lugar onde a gente chamava isso de busca fonética, eles cadastravam um de-para das silabas e existia uma engenharia para localizar baseado nisso, mas não é muito simples

Comment: @Ricardo em português é muito chatinho isso, pq tem combinações que muda todo o sentido dependendo da divisão das palavras. Acho mais eficiente fazer uma aproximação por letras parecidas em vez de busca exata, mas tem que ser analisado caso a caso. Nos meus sistemas já adotei busca por substring, então se a pessoa precisa de Luiz/Luis Augusto, ela pesquisa Lui Augusto e pronto :) - Pra coisa mais complicada, uso uma variante de Levenshtein

Comment: @Bacco, concordo 100% com vc... Não é a melhor solução (estou inclusive estou lendo sobre o FTS aqui), mas é uma solução que funcionava e usavam lá, como eu já vi funcionando resolvi falar.

Comment: @Ricardo acho legal vc ter falado. Só mencionei pq já vi bastante tentando esse caminho e se complicando. Nem acho que é impossível não, só não vi nada pronto otimizado pra português, pq o pessoal acaba tentando reaproveitar coisas feitas pra inglês, e aí nao funciona bem. Se alguém parar pra escrever um algoritmo pensando nas nossas particularidades, até capaz de ficar legal. Só tem que tomar cuidado com coisas que dão mais de uma combinação fonética.

Comment: Se quiser algo pronto, tem essa solução com Levenshtein aqui http://stackoverflow.com/a/4671557/916193

Comment: muito obrigado , vou tentar utilizar acho q deve resolver meu problema. Agora tenho uma dúvida. O quanto isso pesa o script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caso queira fazer uma busca pela fonética das palavras adaptada para o português execute a função:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS transformar_fonetica;

DELIMITER $
CREATE FUNCTION transformar_fonetica(ptexto TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
  DECLARE vtexto             TEXT;
  DECLARE vtexto_apoio       TEXT;
  DECLARE vposicao_atual     INT;
  DECLARE vcaracter_anterior VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE vcaracter_atual    VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE vcaracter_seguinte VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE vsom               VARCHAR(2);
  DECLARE com_acentos        VARCHAR(65);
  DECLARE sem_acentos        VARCHAR(65);

  SET vtexto = UPPER(ptexto);

  SET com_acentos = 'ŠšŽžÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŸÞàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿþƒ';
  SET sem_acentos = 'SsZzAAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYYBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyybf';
  SET vposicao_atual = LENGTH(com_acentos);

  -- Remove acentos
  WHILE vposicao_atual > 0 DO
    SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, SUBSTRING(com_acentos, vposicao_atual, 1), SUBSTRING(sem_acentos, vposicao_atual, 1));
    SET vposicao_atual = vposicao_atual - 1;
  end while;

  -- Remove caracteres inválido
  SET vposicao_atual = 1;

  WHILE vposicao_atual <= LENGTH(vtexto) DO
    SET vcaracter_atual = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual, 1);

    IF INSTR('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', vcaracter_atual) <> 0 THEN
      SET vtexto_apoio = CONCAT(IFNULL(vtexto_apoio, ''), vcaracter_atual);
    END IF;

    SET vposicao_atual = vposicao_atual + 1;
  END WHILE;

  SET vtexto = vtexto_apoio;

  -- Substitui os mais simples
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'SS', 'S');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'SH', 'X');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'XC', 'S');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'QU', 'K');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'CH', 'X');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'PH', 'F');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'LH', 'LI');

  -- Remove duplicados
  SET vposicao_atual = 1;
  SET vtexto_apoio = '';

  WHILE vposicao_atual <= LENGTH(vtexto) DO
    SET vcaracter_atual = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual, 1);

    IF vposicao_atual < LENGTH(vtexto) THEN
      SET vcaracter_seguinte = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual + 1, 1);
    ELSE -- Último caracter não tem motivo para ser verificado
      SET vcaracter_seguinte = '';
    END IF;

    IF vcaracter_atual <> vcaracter_seguinte THEN
      SET vtexto_apoio = CONCAT(vtexto_apoio, vcaracter_atual);
    END IF;

    SET vposicao_atual = vposicao_atual + 1;
  END WHILE;

  SET vtexto = vtexto_apoio;

  -- Troca caracteres pelo som
  SET vposicao_atual = 1;
  SET vtexto_apoio = '';

  WHILE vposicao_atual <= LENGTH(vtexto) DO
    SET vcaracter_atual = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual, 1);

    IF vposicao_atual < LENGTH(vtexto) THEN
      SET vcaracter_seguinte = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual + 1, 1);
    ELSE
      SET vcaracter_seguinte = '';
    END IF;

    -- "B" seguindo de qualquer caracter que não seja "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "R" ou "Y"
    IF vcaracter_atual = 'B' AND INSTR('AEIOURY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN
        SET vsom = 'BI';
    -- "C" seguindo de "E", "I" ou "Y"
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'C' AND INSTR('EIY', vcaracter_seguinte) <> 0 THEN
      SET vsom = 'S';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'C' THEN
      SET vsom = 'K';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'D'  AND INSTR('AEIOURY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN
      SET vsom = 'DI';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'E' THEN
      SET vsom = 'I';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'G' AND INSTR('EIY', vcaracter_seguinte) <> 0  THEN -- GE, GI OU GY
      SET vsom = 'J';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'G' AND vcaracter_seguinte = 'T' THEN -- GT
      SET vsom = '';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'H' THEN
      SET vsom = 'H';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'N' THEN
      SET vsom = 'M';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'P' AND INSTR('AEIOURY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN
      SET vsom = 'PI';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'Q' THEN
      SET vsom = 'K';
    -- QUA, QUE, QUI, QUO ou QUY
    ELSEIF IFNULL(vcaracter_anterior, '') = 'Q' AND vcaracter_atual = 'U' AND INSTR('AEIOY', vcaracter_seguinte) <> 0 THEN
      SET vsom = '';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'W' THEN
      SET vsom = 'V';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'X' THEN
      SET vsom = 'S';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'Y' THEN
      SET vsom = 'I';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'Z' THEN
      SET vsom = 'S';
    ELSE
      SET vsom = vcaracter_atual;
    END IF;

    SET vcaracter_anterior = vcaracter_atual;
    SET vposicao_atual = vposicao_atual + 1;
    SET vtexto_apoio = CONCAT(vtexto_apoio, vsom);
  END WHILE;

  SET vtexto = vtexto_apoio;

  SET vtexto = CONCAT('%', replace(vtexto, ' ', '%'), '%');

  RETURN vtexto;
END
$
```

**A utilização é a seguinte:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM publicacao
 WHERE transformar_fonetica(titulo) LIKE transformar_fonetica('$busca');
```

Se existirem muitos registros a `query` terá problemas de rendimento, então eu aconselho a criação de uma coluna apenas para a fonética e uma `trigger` para atualizá-la.

**Adicionando a nova coluna**

```
ALTER TABLE publicacao ADD fonetica TEXT;
```

**Criação da trigger para atualização**

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER publicacao_fonetica AFTER UPDATE ON publicacao
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if NEW.titulo <=> OLD.titulo THEN
    UPDATE publicacao
       SET fonetica = transformar_fonetica(NEW.titulo)
     WHERE id = OLD.id;
  END IF;
END;
$
```

**Seleção dos dados**

```
SELECT *
  FROM publicacao
 WHERE fonetica LIKE transformar_fonetica('$busca');
```

**Observação:**

A pronuncia de algumas combinações de letra varia de acordo com as palavras, então pode haver discrepâncias. No entanto ainda não encontrei realmente um exemplo em que não funcione.
A busca também funciona para nomes próprios.

Answer (score 4):

Para casos simples, a função SOUNDEX() pode ajudar

```
SELECT title, SOUNDEX(title) FROM soundex_test WHERE SOUNDEX(title) like SOUNDEX('%Farmácia%');
```

Claro que deve fazer algumas adaptações pois Pharmácia é P652 e Farmácia é F652.

Mas ajuda muito em casos onde a fonética pode ter alguma similaridade. Exemplo

```
SELECT title, SOUNDEX(title) FROM soundex_test WHERE SOUNDEX(title) like SOUNDEX('%drug%');
```

Isso retornará registros que contenham termos como

```
drug
droug
droog
```

Se quiser testar, pode usar essas tabela de teste:

```
CREATE TABLE `soundex_test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('1', 'Farmácia');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('4', 'Pharmácia');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('45', 'aucatra');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('55', 'alcatara');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('56', 'alctra');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('71', 'Pharmacia');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('72', 'Farmacia');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('73', 'Memory Card');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('79', 'Gamepad');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('80', 'drug');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('454', 'droug');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('565', 'alcatra');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('3445', 'droog');
INSERT INTO `soundex_test` VALUES ('5656', 'acatra');



SELECT title, SOUNDEX(title) FROM soundex_test WHERE SOUNDEX(title) like SOUNDEX('%alcatra%');
```

Retorna:

```
alcatara
alctra
alcatra
```

Infelizmente não retorna `aucatra` pois o padrão é fonética inglesa. Para saber mais sobre o soundex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Esteja ciente de que isso é apenas uma alternativa e não uma solução definitiva.

Uma outra solução é criar tabelas de dicionários e então você cadastra manualmente as variações. Claro que isso é um trabalho colossal e leva anos, mas é basicamente isso que o Google faz. 
Outra dica é sempre logar o que os usuários digitam nas buscas e você vai perceber certos padrões de erros de digitação, erros de gramática, etc. Aproveite esses logs para compor o dicionário, relacionando-os ao termo correto ou relacionando-os uns aos outros.