# Consulta SQL utilizando varias vezes a mesma função

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Tenho uma função que converte a identificação de uma versão para número, exemplo, de `1.0.0` para `10000`, pois assim consigo filtrar os resultados.

**Função:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_convert_tag_to_number(ptag varchar2(12))
  RETURN NUMBER IS
  vretorno NUMBER(12);
BEGIN
  SELECT ((regexp_substr(ptag,'[^.\D]+',1,1) * 10000) +
          (regexp_substr(ptag,'[^.\D]+',1,2) * 100) +
          (regexp_substr(ptag,'[^.\D]+',1,3) * 1)) 
    INTO vretorno
    FROM dual;

  RETURN(vretorno);
END;
```

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT r.tag
      ,f_convert_tag_to_number(r.tag)
  FROM repositorio r
 WHERE f_convert_tag_to_number(r.tag) BETWEEN
       f_convert_tag_to_number('1.0.0') AND
       f_convert_tag_to_number('1.5.0')
```

Problema, esse exemplo acima de consulta foi somente um exemplo, tenho uma consulta muito maior que utiliza essa função cerca de 15 vezes, e o que eu **quero é reduzir a utilização da função `f_convert_tag_to_number`**

Alguém sabe alguma forma?

Obrigado

Comment: Você pode criar uma coluna com a `tag` convertida pra número na tabela e uma trigger que atualizará a coluna toda vez você fizer uma alteração. Exemplo em MySQL [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167184/consulta-inteligente-com-mysql/167252#167252) na segunda parte da resposta

Comment: Vou analisar se a coluna calculada com `trigger` atende a todas as situações, caso atender posto a resposta com a `trigger`. Queria que tivesse outra forma, mesmo assim obrigado @Sorack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma nova coluna para espelhar a informação que você quer:

```
ALTER TABLE repositorio ADD numeric_tag NUMBER(12);
```

E preenche-la através de uma `trigger` ao inserir ou atualizar:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_conversao_tag
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE of tag
ON repositorio
FOR EACH ROW
AS
BEGIN
  :new.numeric_tag = f_convert_tag_to_number(:new.tag);
END;
```

Utilizando na `query` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT r.tag
      ,r.numeric_tag
  FROM repositorio r
 WHERE r.numeric_tag BETWEEN
       f_convert_tag_to_number('1.0.0') AND
       f_convert_tag_to_number('1.5.0')
```

Comment: Já melhora e muito, vamos aguardar se alguém tem alguma ideia, ai já marco como aceita.. obrigado @Sorack

Comment: @David Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: Pode deixar, esperar mais uns dias, vlw