# Identificar duplicidades e possíveis duplicidades através de scores/ranking

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma banco em mysql que tem informações de usuários onde tenho que definir o que é duplicidade ou não.

Observações: O campos NOME_MAE e DATA_NASC não são obrigatórios.
Exemplos de registros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só fazendo o soundex do nome da pessoa e do da mãe não adianta, pois como no exemplo a palavra IGNACIO(I252) dá um soundex diferente de INACIO(I520).
Pretendia fazer um sistema de scores para identificar as duplicidade e as possíveis duplicidades. 
Vou acrescentar a variável INICIAIS_NOME, para ajudar com o problema do soundex. Mas não faço idéia de como montar esse SCORE. Alguma ajuda??
Pode ser em PHP ou MYSQL.
Obrigado!

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta resposta: [Consulta inteligente com MySQL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167184/consulta-inteligente-com-mysql/167252#167252)

Comment: Tenho uma função em Oracle que ao comparar esses dois nomes ela me informa que são 92% similares. Algo assim ajudaria?

Comment: Dica de um caminho para você tentar, eu faria várias queries, daria union, transformava em subquery (colocava isso depois do from) e dava um sum, talvez utilizar uns CASE WHEN... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: Então "@Sorack", sobre este link que vc informou eu já estou fazendo deste jeito....o problema com o nome está 90% resolvido, visto que uso um soundexBR para os nomes. O problema é quando tenho duplicidades com idades diferentes ou sem nome da mãe em algum...entendeu....repare na imagem do exemplo.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, vou dar uma pesquisada e ver se tem a mesma para MySql