# Select com like detalhado

Tags: mysql

Como realizar uma select tendo em vista que pode não ser uma comparação exata no banco de dados. Eu sei que existe o `LIKE`, mas eu já tentei e não surtiu o efeito desejado.

O problema é  seguinte, tenho que pesquisa no banco por um nome que pode faltar uma letra no fim ou no inicio, por exemplo, no banco pode está assim **JOSIVAN SOUSA** mas a entrada da pesquisa pode ser:

- JOSIVAN SOUS
- JOSIVAN DE SOUSA
- OSIVAN SOUSA

E por aí vai.

Comment: Relacionada: [Consulta inteligente com MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167184/consulta-inteligente-com-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Não tem segredo.

```
Select * from suatabela
where seucampo like '%OSIVAN SOUSA%'
```

Comment: Esse select não me dá o resultado desejado

Comment: O termo pesquisa pode ser JOSIVAN DE SOUSA e o que está no banco pode ser JOSIVAN SOUSA

Comment: isso é gambiara...

Comment: Seguindo sua descrição do problema, onde pode faltar um carácter no fim ou no inicio do nome completo. A única solução viável é do @MarconcilioSouza. Pois se não qual seria o padrão de busca? :S

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
  from suatabela
 where seucampo like '%_OSIVAN SOUSA_%'
```

Comment: Não funciona para o meu problema

Comment: `_` diz que necessita ter algum caracter naquela posição, não atende a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

`MySQL` possui um conjunto de funções que podes usar para trabalhar com String, por exemplo `SUBSTRING`.

> SELECT * FROM `users`  WHERE 1=1 
>       AND
>       ( SUBSTRING(name,2,16) = "OSIVAN DE SOUSA"
>        OR
>        SUBSTRING(name,1,15) = "JOSIVAN DE SOUS"
>        )